# "config.h" file not found react native iOS

Tags: react-native

I tried almost all the solutions given to resolve this issue but nothing is working for me.

This issue is occurring when I am opening .xcodeproj

Can anyone please provide a permanent solution for this?

Comment: Deleting node_modules folder from your project directory and running yarn install worked for me. If you are using npm, use npm install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Close your Xcode.

2) Open Terminal, go to your project's root folder and do:

```
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/
```

3) Run the configure script:

```
./configure
```

4) Open Xcode and try to run your app.

Comment: how to run ./configure script?

Comment: @AyazAkbar run through terminal

Answer (score 1):

You need to change to the legacy build system in Xcode 10 and install third party scripts manually.

1. File > Project/Workspace settings
   Build System: dropdown > change to Legacy Build system
2. Follow this to manually install third party scripts for RN:

Clean RN cache

```
$ rm -rf ~/.rncache
```

Re-install the deps

```
$ cd your_project_path
$ rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install
```

Then install the third-party

```
$ cd node_modules/react-native/scripts
$ ./ios-install-third-party.sh
```

Run the commands below if glog installation failed.

```
$ cd ../third-party/glog-0.3.x
$ ./configure
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by Xcode's recent update. I fixed this issue by the following easy steps and I found this to be the best solution after searching for a while and tried many.

1. Go to Xcode > File > Project Settings
2. Build System > Select "Legacy Build System"
3. Go to terminal and run `cd /to-your-project-folder`
4. Run `rm -rf node_modules && yarn` (to remove node_modules and reinstall them)
5. Go back to Xcode > Product > Clean
6. Product > press option key and then click Clean Build Folder
7. And click the clean button

Now you can run the project from Xcode or on the terminal run `yarn run ios` or `react-native run-ios`

Credits to Spencer Carli's video on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/sLMCmXT4i9A)

I hope this helps :-)